# OpenShift: 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: node.js, openshift, haproxy, http-status-code-503, ghost

I've been working on my Ghost theme for the last few hours, and suddenly this error. Attached is a copy of my HAProxy status output.

[image]

I've restarted both NodeJS and HAProxy.  Neither restart fixed the issue, and both are showing as running in the console.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: This should probably go on serverfault instead

Comment: Oh, my bad.  Is there a quick way to move it over?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the culprit. In the nodejs log, I found the following:

```
ERROR: [default.hbs] The partial contact could not be found 
Rendering Error Page 
Ghost caught a processing error in the middleware layer.
```

I returned to the theme I was editing when this problem occurred and cross-referenced all requests for partials with the partials files themselves, and found that I had misspelled one.  Correcting that, fixed this issue immediately.

**My 503 was specific to an error in my Ghost theme.**